# Flask form not sending post request

Tags: python-3.x, flask, post

When i press any of the three input buttons in the HTML form below it will not send a POST request to my messages() function. I have been trying to figure out how to specify which input button is pressed in the form and so that is why there are different if statements for each button in my function. I had been searching for that for days until realizing it wasn't even sending a POST request in the first place.

I realize there are other questions with almost the same title as this one but I have looked through them all and none could help me with my problem so please do not mark this as a duplicate post.

If you need more code than this just ask! Thank You!

```
@app.route("/messages", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def messages():
    values = users.query.all()
    try:
        using = session['username']
        passing = session['password']
    except:
        flash("You Need To Log In First!")
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    tic_value = ""
    global driver
    price_list = []
    count = -1
    user_ticker_db = users.query.filter_by(username=using, password=passing).first()
    db.session.commit()
    for p in user_ticker_db.tick_values:
        if p != " ":
            tic_value += p 
        if p == " ":
            price_list.append(tic_value)
            tic_value = ""
    my_prices = []
    my_news = []
    while True:
        for x in price_list:
            count += 1
            driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q={price_list[count]}+stock+price")
            price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div[10]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/g-card-section/div/g-card-section/span[1]/span/span[1]").text
            driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={price_list[count]}+stock+price&client=firefox-b-1-d&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4nJvnz6fsAhXSXM0KHR4gBTgQ_AUoAnoECCcQBA&biw=1036&bih=569&dpr=1.5")
            news = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div[9]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/g-card/div/div/div[2]/a/div/div[2]/div[2]").text
            my_prices.append(f"${price}")
            my_news.append(news)
        return render_template("messages.html", my_stock = zip(price_list, my_prices, my_news), amount = len(price_list))
        if request.method == "POST":
            #It never reaches here...
            print("post request")
            if request.form.get("Reload_Prices"):
                print("its working")
                for x in price_list:
                    count += 1
                    driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q={price_list[count]}+stock+price")
                    price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div[10]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/g-card-section/div/g-card-section/span[1]/span/span[1]").text
                    driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={price_list[count]}+stock+price&client=firefox-b-1-d&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4nJvnz6fsAhXSXM0KHR4gBTgQ_AUoAnoECCcQBA&biw=1036&bih=569&dpr=1.5")
                    news = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div[9]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/g-card/div/div/div[2]/a/div/div[2]/div[2]").text
                    my_prices.append(f"${price}")
                    my_news.append(news)
                return render_template("messages.html", my_stock = zip(price_list, my_prices, my_news), amount = len(price_list))
            elif "Remove_Ticker" in request.form:
                ticker_request = request.form["tick_value"]
                try:
                    remove_ticker_db = users.query.filter_by(username=using, password=passing).first()
                    remove_ticker_db.tick_values = remove_ticker_db.tick_values - (ticker_request + " ")
                    db.session.commit()
                    flash("Ticker Removed")
                except:
                    flash("Ticker Not Saved")
            elif request.form["action"] == "Add_Ticker":
                print("loading")
                ticker_request = request.form["tick_value"]
                try:
                    print("worked")
                    driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q={ticker_request}+stock+price")
                    price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div[10]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/g-card-section/div/g-card-section/span[1]/span/span[1]").text
                    add_ticker_db = users.query.filter_by(username=using, password=passing).first()
                    add_ticker_db.tick_values = add_ticker_db.tick_values + (ticker_request + " ")
                    db.session.commit()
                    flash("Ticker Added")
                except:
                    print("Broken")
                    flash("Invalid Ticker Symbol")
                    pass
                #item.tick_values
                # Need to add the values from the ticker input box to the database so that when a specific user logs on it will show their stocks
                # Will also add a column of text with the names of the tickers you have selected and you can type it into the box and click remove to get rid of it from database
    else:
        print("failed")
        return render_template("messages.html", my_prices=f"$aapl price", my_news="aapl News")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My HTML file.

```
    <form action="{{ url_for('messages') }}" method='POST'>
        <input type='submit', name='action', value='Reload_Prices'>
        <br>
        <input type='submit', name='action', value='Add_Ticker'>
        <input type='text', name='tick_value'>
        <input type='submit', name='action', value='Remove_Ticker'> 
        {% for ticker in ticker_values %}
            <br>
            <input type='text', value=ticker>
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
```

Comment: Remove the comma in the `<form>` element. That'll rule out a problem on the HTML side.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith done.

Comment: One way you'll see 404s is if you do app.run() before the @app.route()

Comment: @DaveW.Smith You mean app.run(debug=True) command?

Comment: Either form (debug=True, debug=False) will have the same effect if they happen before routes are specified. Can you show us where that happens?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I believe i add what you asked for but if not i can add more.

Comment: I don't see where you set `app`, but `@app.route(...)` wouldn't have worked, so I'll trust that part. What shows up in the logs when you try to submit? And if you have your browser's development tools enabled, do they report an error when you try to submit?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith how do i enable browser development tools?

Comment: Depends on what browser you're using. If Chrome, right-click on something and select Inspect from the menu. Then click Network on the top of the tab that shows up, then try to submit the form. You'll get an interesting view of what's happening under the covers.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I rewrote the code and it seems to work now.. will post as answer

Comment: For me, I had to restart the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure even exactly what the error was from but i completely rewrote the code and it seems to work fine this time, with a few minor bugs. Anyways here it is... if you find what the error was feel free to post it.

```
@app.route("/messages", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def messages():
    values = users.query.all()
    try:
        using = session['username']
        passing = session['password']
    except:
        flash("You Need To Log In First!")
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    tic_value = ""
    global driver
    global my_prices
    global my_news
    global price_list
    price_list = []
    count = -1
    user_ticker_db = users.query.filter_by(username=using, password=passing).first()
    db.session.commit()
    for p in user_ticker_db.tick_values:
        if p != " ":
            tic_value += p 
        if p == " ":
            price_list.append(tic_value)
            tic_value = ""
    my_prices = []
    my_news = []
    for x in price_list:
        try:
            count += 1
            driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q={price_list[count]}+stock+price")
            price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div[10]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/g-card-section/div/g-card-section/span[1]/span/span[1]").text
            driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={price_list[count]}+stock+price&client=firefox-b-1-d&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4nJvnz6fsAhXSXM0KHR4gBTgQ_AUoAnoECCcQBA&biw=1036&bih=569&dpr=1.5")
            news = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div[9]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/g-card/div/div/div[2]/a/div/div[2]/div[2]").text
            my_prices.append(f"${price}")
            my_news.append(news)
        except:
            print("Error loading tickers/news")
        
    if request.form.get('reload', False) == "Reload_Prices":
        count = -1
        print("its working")
        for x in price_list:
            try:
                count += 1
                driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q={price_list[count]}+stock+price")
                price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div[10]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/g-card-section/div/g-card-section/span[1]/span/span[1]").text
                driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={price_list[count]}+stock+price&client=firefox-b-1-d&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4nJvnz6fsAhXSXM0KHR4gBTgQ_AUoAnoECCcQBA&biw=1036&bih=569&dpr=1.5")
                news = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div[9]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/g-card/div/div/div[2]/a/div/div[2]/div[2]").text
                my_prices.append(f"${price}")
                my_news.append(news)
            except:
                print("Error loading tickers/news")
        return render_template("messages.html", my_stock = zip(price_list, my_prices, my_news), amount = len(price_list))
        count = 0
    elif request.form.get('remove', False) == "Remove_Ticker":
        print("removing")
        ticker_request = request.form["tick_value"]
        try:
            remove_ticker_db = users.query.filter_by(username=using, password=passing).first()
            remove_ticker_db.tick_values = str(remove_ticker_db.tick_values).replace(str(ticker_request + " "), "")
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            print("error when removing")
        return render_template("messages.html", my_stock = zip(price_list, my_prices, my_news), amount = len(price_list))
                   
    elif request.form.get('add', False) == "Add_Ticker":
        print("adding")
        ticker_request = request.form["tick_value"]
        try:
            driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q={ticker_request}+stock+price")
            price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div[10]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/g-card-section/div/g-card-section/span[1]/span/span[1]").text
            add_ticker_db = users.query.filter_by(username=using, password=passing).first()
            add_ticker_db.tick_values = str(add_ticker_db.tick_values) + str(ticker_request + " ")
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            print("error when adding")
        return render_template("messages.html", my_stock = zip(price_list, my_prices, my_news), amount = len(price_list))
        
    else:
        for x in price_list:
            driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q={price_list[count]}+stock+price")
            price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div[10]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/g-card-section/div/g-card-section/span[1]/span/span[1]").text
            driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={price_list[count]}+stock+price&client=firefox-b-1-d&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4nJvnz6fsAhXSXM0KHR4gBTgQ_AUoAnoECCcQBA&biw=1036&bih=569&dpr=1.5")
            news = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div[9]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/g-card/div/div/div[2]/a/div/div[2]/div[2]").text
            my_prices.append(f"${price}")
            my_news.append(news)
    
        return render_template("messages.html", my_stock = zip(price_list, my_prices, my_news))
```

Then here is my HTML

```
<form action="{{url_for('messages')}}", method='POST'>  
    <input type='submit', name='reload', value='Reload_Prices'>
    <br>
    <input type='submit', name='add', value='Add_Ticker'>
    <input type='text', name='tick_value'>
    <input type='submit', name='remove', value='Remove_Ticker'>
</form>
```